# ArangoSearch on json object fields

Tags: arangodb

Suppose I have a document with an object for a field:

```
{f: {a:{a1:v1,b1:v2},b:{a3:v3,b3:v4}}}
```

I'd like to do the same search for words in all leafs. The view would have a single word index for the entire object instead of independent indexes for each sub-structure.  Thus treating the entire structure like a single text document for searching.

I was hoping to use an aql analyzer to concatenate the values of the fields in the structure and pipeline it to another analyzer but I can't see how to get the f object for @param.

Is this impossible?  Without this I will have to OR the same search criteria for dozens of sub fields. Ranking the results properly would also be a complex exercise. A single index would make a world of difference in complexity and performance.